# .NET parallel LINQ equivalent in Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, plinq

I want to be able to do something like this in Ruby:

```
(new[]{"http://google.com", "http://facebook.com", "http://microsoft.com", "http://twitter.com", "http://stackoverflow.com"})
.AsParallel()
.Select(q => WebRequest.Create(q).GetResponse())
```

This also should preserve order of elements and use deferred execution.
Are there any options available?

Comment: The only real solution I found so far is manually managing threads in a loop, which does not provide deferred execution and pretty low level.

Comment: You're going to want to put that solution in the question because SO is not properly used as a board to write code for other people. However, if you've tried something it shows that you put in some effort and people are much more apt to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) gem, which is a wrapper around the `curl` library, has a "multi" mode that can fetch a number of URLs in parallel.

From the example:

```
# Make multiple GET requests
easy_options = { :follow_location => true }
multi_options = { :pipeline => true }

Curl::Multi.get('url1','url2','url3','url4','url5', easy_options, multi_options) do |easy|
  # do something interesting with the easy response
  puts easy.last_effective_url
end
```

Comment: As far as I am understand this is not common solution for managing collections in asynchronous way?

Comment: There are many different ways of doing asynchronous networking in Ruby such as threads or fibers or, in this case, an application specific implementation.